# lcapy (python) gives wrong dc voltages on capacitors connected in series

Tags: capacitor

I am trying to solve with python lcapy package this trivial problem of two capacitors connected in series. The circuit named "a" is coded as:

```
from lcapy import Circuit
a = Circuit("""
    V 1 0 dc; down
    C1 1 2; right=2.0
    C2 2 0_2; down
    W 0 0_2; right
    """)
```

[image]

This circuit is constructed following the lcapy tutorial "the DC voltage divider", where I have placed capacitors instead of resistors. If I want to know the voltages on each capacitor and the source I issue this command:

```
a.C1.V, a.C2.V, a.V.V
```

and get the strange answer:

V/2, V/2, V.

That is, voltages on both capacitors are equal to each other and to V/2.

However if I change the voltage source from dc to ac (or v(t)):

```
    V 1 0 ac; down   # 3-rd line in the code above
```

or arbitrary v(t):

```
    V 1 0 {v(t)}; down   # 3-rd line in the code above
```

then the answer is correct:

V * C2 / (C1 + C2)  # voltage on C1

V * C1 / (C1 + C2)  # voltage on C2

The question is why the answer is incorrect in dc case and how to handle this case.

Of course I could replace two capacitors by one here, but I just want to be confident when building more complicated stuff and understand what is going on.

Other things I tried:

1. created another scheme "d" by simplifying initial "a". Command:

```
d = a.simplify()
```

and got the scheme "d" with a single capacitor having C = 1/ (1/C1 + 1/C2) capacitance. So simplification looks correct. But that's not what I need.

2. read the manual only to find that lcapy uses modified nodal analysis which falls in trouble of singular matrix when there are capacitors in series. With no clue how to work around.

My horse is good old CentOS 7 with python 3.7 and
lcapy.**version** = 1.17

Comment: If C1 = C2 then both answers agree.

Comment: The problem is that in DC analysis, the voltage at node 2 can be any arbitrary value; this is why you get the "singular matrix" and the math fails. You need to supply more information, such as the initial voltage on one of the capacitors before the source is applied.

Comment: "You need to supply more information, such as the initial voltage on one of the capacitors" ...or perhaps add some big resistors in parallel with the caps.